# DateDiff Rounding in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datediff

I have a table that contains the last date/time a particular function was ran. In my stored procedure, I want to return 1 if the current date/time is more than an hour away from the last time it was ran and 0 if it was less. Currently I have this:

```
IF((SELECT TOP 1 DATEDIFF(HH,LastRunDateTime,GETDATE()) FROM myTable) >= 1)
BEGIN
    -- run statement to update LastRunDateTime
        return 1;
END
ELSE
    return 0;
END
```

How does rounding work with DateDiff?

Is there a better way to only return 1 if it has been more than an hour?

Comment: Exists may has a better performance here and it's more Intuitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(hh, LastRunDateTime, GETDATE()) >= 1 THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END
```

Reference:

- [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

> How does rounding work with DateDiff?

The **datepart Boundaries** section in the documentation link provided lists such information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
IF DATEADD(hour, LastRunDateTime, 1) <= GETDATE() BEGIN
    RETURN 1;
END;
ELSE BEGIN
    RETURN 0;
END;
```

DateDiff is a little more subtle than just subtracting two datetimes.  It actually tells you how many "boundaries" are crossed between the two.  For example:

```
PRINT DATEDIFF(HH, '2010-12-07T03:59:59', '2010-12-07T04:00:00');
PRINT DATEDIFF(HH, '2010-12-07T04:00:00', '2010-12-07T04:59:59');
```

prints the following:

```
1
0
```

which is confusing, because the second pair of datetimes are farther apart.  This functionality is great when you need it, but counterintuitive when you don't.